# What was the relevance of the scene where police officers were protesting against the ICAC near the beginning of "The Goldfinger?"

Tags: plot-explanation, the-goldfinger

Near the beginning of [the 2023 "The Goldfinger"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Goldfinger_(2023_film)) movie, there's a scene that depicts police officers protesting (first peacefully, then not so peacefully) against the ICAC, and I'm having a hard time understanding the relevance of the scene to the plot.

As far as I can tell, maybe the main motivator might've been just cultural/historical/political context, and not necessarily a plot device — I didn't understand the value of showing that the police and the ICAC were at odds, because 99.9% of the conflict in the plot is *not* between these two entities.

If not for historical setting, only a single scene later on potentially calls-back to its relevance, but it is given relatively little importance and it mostly still hints at relevant cultural-historical relevance:

> When Lau's wife slaps Ching, the police officer present seems to side with Lau and overlook the incident — potentially showing this conflict is no more? Ching makes a remark in the lines of "The police and the ICAC are in cahoots? That's too bad for the commoner."

Am I missing something with regards to that conflict's relevance to the storyline? Alternatively, what specific context is being conveyed in terms of social tensions at the time?